# What is the meaning of "bruing/brewing conversation" or "bru/brew some conversation"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, expressions, phrasal-verbs

I heard this in a talk show. But I couldn't catch the word. Like the man said -

> I can't wait to bru/brew some exciting conversations.

I don't know, what does that mean?

I found on my research that "what's brewing?" = "What's cooking?"/"what's going on?". I couldn't find any word called "bru/bruing". But brew means boiling/steeping etc. And in slang terms it brew means coffee. So I don't get what this sentence means.

Comment: It's using "brew" as a metaphor. People often have conversations while drinking coffee or tea.

Answer (score 1):

Your research is correct so far as it goes. There is more that can be said about *brew*.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brew)
> *brew*
> *verb* transitive
> to make beer
> *verb* intransitive or transitive
> If you brew tea or coffee, you add boiling water to it to make a hot drink, and if it brews, it gradually develops flavour in the container in which it was made

Brewing beer or hot drinks takes some time as various reactions occur and flavours develop. From these meanings comes the idea that something can be prepared so as to develop slowly. This gives us the idiom of:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brew)
> If an unpleasant situation or a storm is brewing, you feel that it is about to happen

Or we speak of brewing a cold when developing a cold.

The brewing does not necessarily have to presage something unpleasant. Going back to the original meaning of preparing beer or a drink, it may be something pleasant or neutral. Hence your example of brewing a conversation, which refers to gathering the thoughts and ideas (and perhaps the people) necessary to start and continue a conversation.